# perl: cannot unlink file: Permission denied at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/File/Temp.pm

Tags: perl, selenium

I am trying to run a perl script using selenium webdriver.
After successful execution of script, I am getting following error:
*

> cannot unlink file for
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\89qNk6oDJh\cert8.db: Permission
>   denied at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/File/Temp.pm line 1616.

*

And the line 1616 in Temp.pm looks like this:

```
eval { rmtree($self->{REALNAME}, $File::Temp::DEBUG, 0); };
```

What can be the cause?

My script is simple perl program, it creates a webdriver object and open a URL and gets the title.

Comment: So what are those permissions on that file you are trying to unlink?

Comment: Sounds like the browser is still running, and keeping this file locked somehow.

Comment: @zdim Actually, this error comes for all the files which are created in the Temp folder(in this case "89qNk6oDJh").  And in windows checklist I am seeing that all users have full control on the files. @tripleee I use `$webDriver->close();` to close the browser. It should close browser.

Comment: OK, that matters a lot for the question.  I'd suggest an edit, add this information.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows a file cannot be deleted while it is open.